# Return differing rows in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I apologize for the basic non specific title. I can’t conceptualize how to ask this question or write the query I need in tsql. Any suggestions or guidance would be helpful. I have four columns that matter to me in a table:

```
c1(primarykey), c2, c3, c4
```

For any two rows, If c3 and c4 match but c2 doesn’t I want to return the rows. Amplify this to the entire table.

I’ve tried joining on a temp table then finding the difference through a left join on the table to itself but maybe I’m doing something incorrectly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, MIN(c2) OVER(PARTITION BY c3,c4) AS m, MAX(c2) OVER(PARTITION BY c3,c4) AS m2
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE m <> m2;
```

Comment: This completes on very large data set in exceptional time. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Windowing functions are your pond . Great and very smart approach!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the *rows*, then `exists` is a good way to go:

```
select t
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.c3 = t.c3 and t2.c4 = t.c4 and
                    t2.c2 <> t.c2
             );
```

You do not mention `NULL` values in your question.  If you have `NULL` values in any of the three columns, you would need to tweak the logic.

If you just wanted the `c3`/`c4` pairs with different `c2` values, you can use aggregation:

```
select c3, c4
from t
group by c3, c4
having min(c2) <> max(c2);
```

Finally, if you wanted to see pairs of non-matches on a single row, then:

```
select t.*, t2.c1, t2.c2
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.c3 = t.c3 and t2.c4 = t.c4 and
        t2.c2 > t.c1;
```

Comment: Great and comprehensive answer!

Comment: I appreciate you mentioning exists, providing an example and bringing up the inevitable null issue. Thank for you the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

With EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where c2 <> t.c2 and c3 = t.c3 and c4 = t.c4 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`Except`**

```
SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4 FROM TABLE1
EXCEPT
SELECT C4,C3,C2,C1 FROM TABLE1
```

This will check all the column values and if any of the value doesn't match then that record will be returns. More over you can add more columns to this query to match values.